# Remap windows 8 edge swipe?

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

Is it possible to remaps the edge swipe functionality on Windows 8?  I would like to be able to make the left edge swipe change tabs in my browser (ctrl+t) and right swipe switch apps (alt+tab or windows+tab)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remap Windows 8 edge swipe keys to some other keys using a good key mapper.

I prefer [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/). [Here is a post I wrote](http://www.programmerfish.com/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-8-using-sharpkeys/), which explains a step by step procedure to remap the keys using SharpKeys. It works fine with Windows 8.

All you have to do is open SharpKeys, click *Add*, and then add a new mapping. Finally, write the changes to the registry.

Comment: and where are edge gestures keys in that program?